# Populating select list with JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

So I have some less than desireable JSON being returned from a web service and it goes a little somethin like this (please excuse the '?' characters):

```
{
    "d": [
      "AI,Appenzell Innerrhoden ", 
      "AR,Appenzell Ausserrhoden ", 
      "BE,Bern ", 
      "BL,Basel", 
      "BS,Basel", 
      "FR,Fribourg ", 
      "GE,Gen�ve ", 
      "GL,Glarus ", 
      "GR,Graub�nden ", 
      "JU,Jura ", 
      "LU,Luzern ", 
      "NE,Neuch�tel ", 
      "NW,Nidwalden ", 
      "OW,Obwalden ", 
      "SG,Sankt Gallen ", 
      "SH,Schaffhausen ", 
      "SO,Solothurn ", 
      "SZ,Schwyz ", 
      "TG,Thurgau ", 
      "TI,Ticino ", 
      "UR,Uri ", 
      "VD,Vaud ", 
      "VS,Valais ", 
      "ZG,Zug ", 
      "ZH,Z�rich "
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to populate a select list ('#state') but I keep getting 'undefined'
Here's the ajax call - issue in success function:

```
var country = {};
country.request=$('#country').val();
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'webserviceURL',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(country),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data){
          var toAppend = '';
           $.each(data.d,function(i,o){
            toAppend += '<option>'+o.id+'</option>';
          });
         $('#state').append(toAppend);
        },
        error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;

            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Reflecting first comment, now displays 'undefined' but has the correct number of 'undefined's'

UPDATE 2: I need the formatting to be`<option value="AI">Appenzell Innerrhoden</option>`

Comment: try, $.each(data.d,function(i,o)

Comment: @BatScream it is returning 'undefined' for each item, although it is shoing the correct number of 'undefined'

Comment: try, toAppend += '<option>'+o+'</option>';

Comment: Man that's close. Probably my fault for not being clear enough. I need the 'AI' to be the option value and the 'Appenzell Innerrhoden' to be the option text. So it needs to be <option value="AI">Appenzell Innerhoden</option>

Comment: o.split(",")[0] will give you AI, and o.split(",")[1] will give you Appenzell Innerhoden.

Comment: Awesome! thanks, split did the trick. If internet points matter, put this in an answer and Ill gladly accept! Really appreciate it man, thank you.

Comment: Most Welcome. Have just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `$each` function parameter as below:

```
$.each(data.d,function(i,o){
var id = o.split(",")[0];
var value = o.split(",")[1];
toAppend += "<option value="+id+">"+value+"</option>";
});
```

The problem with your code was, you were accessing the JSON `object` rather than the `d` key inside it.

Comment: I like that, is there any benefit to doing each key in a var, as opposed to doing it in the toAppend function?

Comment: It depends upon the developers. Some follow it as a good programming practice. It becomes easy to read and maintain the code, that way.

Answer (score 1):

Please change:

```
toAppend += '<option>'+o.id+'</option>';
```

To:

```
toAppend += '<option value="' + o.split(',')[0] + '">' + o.split(',')[1] + '</option>';
```

Comment: Yup thats exactly what @BatScream had in his comment. Works.